# Expecting 'EndNew' command to close 'New'. Genexus

Tags: genexus

I'm tring to make a new record in my table, so i try:

```
New
                PEDIDOCodigo = &pedcodrevenda
                PEDIDOEmpcod = &pagempcod
                PEDIDOTipo = 2
                PEDIDOEmissao = &OrderByIdResponse.data.date_added
                TIPODECOBRANCACodigo = &TIPODECOBRANCACodigo
                Clicod = &clicod
                PEDIDOVendedor = &clirep
                PEDIDOVendedorComissao = &PedComPai
                PEDIDOVendedor2 = 0
                PEDIDOVendedor2Comissao = 0
                PEDIDODesconto = &DescontoPedidoPercentual
                PEDIDOTransportadora = &Cliente.CliTra
                PEDIDOTipoFrete = 'F'
                CONDICAOPAGAMENTOId = &CONDICAOPAGAMENTOid
                PEDIDOObservacao = substr(&OrderByIdResponse.data.comment, 1, 80)
                PEDIDOObservacao2 = &pedobs2
                TabPreCodi = &GTABELA
                PEDIDOEmpresaId = empresalogin()
                PEDIDOUf = &cliest
                PEDIDONomee = upper(substr(&OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_firstname,1, 60))
                PEDIDOEnde = upper(substr(&EnderecoEntregaCompleto, 1, 60))
                PEDIDOEndeNro = &OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_number_home
                PEDIDOEndeComplemento = &OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_address_2
                PEDIDOBaie = upper(substr(&OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_neighborhood, 1, 40))
                PEDIDOCide = upper(substr(&OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_city, 1, 30))
                PEDIDOCepe = &OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_postcode, 1, 9
                PEDIDOEste = upper(GetUfPorNome(&OrderByIdResponse.data.payment_zone.Trim()))
                PEDIDOStatus = &pedsit
            EndNew
```

But i'm receiving:

> error src0064: Expecting 'EndNew' command to close 'New'. (Procedure
>   'Irroba.ImportarPedido' Source, Line: 493, Char: 4, Details)

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of syntax error that's preventing the procedure to be saved correctly. I would comment out half of the assignments inside the New/EndNew, and see if the error still shows. If it doesn't start uncommenting half of the commented lines until you find which one is causing the problem, and if commenting the first half of the assignments didn't help, continue commenting until it does. Once you narrowed down which line is causing problems, post an Edit to do a follow-up.

Comment: The line  PEDIDOCepe = `&OrderByIdResponse.data.shipping_postcode, 1, 9` is wrong. You are probably missing calling `susbtr` or need to remove `, 1, 9`